# What can each defense/building be upgraded to on each Town Hall?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I would just like to know what the maxed level of each building is for each Town Hall.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to the [Town Hall Page](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall) on the Wikia.

scroll down to ***Resource, Army and Other Buildings Max Level By Town Hall***, this table and the one bellow it ***Defensive Buildings Max Available Level*** will have the information your looking for. (apologies for no anchor links, Wiki does not use them)

Taking Jeffrey Lin's advice i'll summarize some of the more important stuff for the first 5 levels

```
TH Lv. | Gold and Elixir Collectors | Gold and Elixir Storage | Barracks
   1   |             2              |          1              |    3
   2   |             4              |          3              |    4
   3   |             6              |          6              |    5
   4   |             8              |          8              |    6
   5   |            10              |          9              |    7

TH Lv. | Cannon | Archer Wall | Wall
   1   |    2   |      -      |  -
   2   |    3   |      2      |  2
   3   |    4   |      3      |  3
   4   |    5   |      4      |  4
   5   |    6   |      6      |  5
```

however there are a lot of buildings and the tables don't format well here on Stack Exchange

Comment: You might want to quote the wiki here in case the page ever disappears.

Answer (score -1):

Maxes for th 7.

Defenses

- Cannons - max Level 8
- Archer towers - max level 8
- Mortars - max level 5
- Wizard towers - max level 4
- Air defenses - max level 5
- Barbarian king - max level 5
- Hidden tesla - max level 3
- Air sweeper - max level 3

WALLS

- Walls - max level 7

TROOPS

- Dragons max level 2
- Archers max level 4
- Barbarians max level 4
- Giants max level 4
- Wall breakers max level 4
- Healers max level 2
- Goblins max level 4
- Balloons max level 4
- Minions max level 2
- Hog riders max level 2
- Wizards max level 4

LOOT

- Elixir storages max level 11
- Gold storages max level 11
- Elixir collectors max level 11
- Gold mines max level 11
- Dark elixir storage max level 2
- Dark elixir drill max level 3

BARRACKS

- Barracks max level 9
- Dark barracks max level 2

TRAPS
- spring trap level 2
- Bombs max level 4
- Giant bombs max level 2
- Air bomb max level 3
- Seeking air mine max level 1

LABORATORY MAX LEVEL 5

CLAN CASTLE MAX LEVEL 3

ARMY CAMP MAX LEVEL 6.

SPELL FACTORY MAX LEVEL 3.

SPELLS

- Lightning spell max level 4.
- Healing spell max level 4.
- Rage spell max level 4.